# <h1> image repeated before and after?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want a dotted pattern to repeat-x either side of my H1 titles.

Can this be done?

Note: Some of my H1's are placed over background images, not always on a solid colour.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking to do

[image]

Comment: Do you want it on *all* of your <h1> tags?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwNprm

Comment: Does not quite work for me. If I increase the dotted line to 6px I get squares, I need circles :( http://jsfiddle.net/craignewman78/2y3x15fu/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple JQuery solution.

```
<h1 class="dots">Jasper</h1>

<script language="javascript">
var dots = '.................';
$('.dots').prepend(dots);
$('.dots').append(dots);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `::before` and `::after` selectors.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4kqxj61e/

Comment: This almost works! My problem is two fold. 1: The dots are a set amount and do not go all the way 100% width and 2: When I view that on mobile screen sizes the dots push some of my h1's off to the right. Is there any way to do this but have overflow hidden maybe?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the problem or create a fiddle with your code and post it here? Thanks